# List first entry from reverse foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following Models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = 
    description = 

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How to list all first chapters by *date added* from all books? like

I want to have a queryset or a list of Chapter, to display in templates.

Comment: How is your date field defined?

Comment: `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` that way @blhsing

Answer (score 1):

Try using get_context_data in your view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ViewName, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['chapters'] = Chapter.objects.filter(chapter_number=1).order_by('date_created') 
    # order_by orders the queryset based on the field you specify. You could also use ('-date_created) to reverse the order.
    return context
```

and then in your template:

```
{% for chapter in chapters %}
 <p>{{ chapter.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It's kind of difficult to say since I don't know the name of your DateTimeField or other attributes you have specified for Chapter.

Comment: not exactly, he needs to display Only first chapters from every book

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [default ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#ordering) for your `Chapters`
Then `.first()` will be ordered by date

```
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('chapter_set')

for book in books:
    print(book.chapter_set.first())
```